# Generic error in GDI+

Tags: c#, gdi+, bmp

I am saving images from camera in a loop but some times it gives generic error in gdi+ in some system while i use i7 4gb ram and it dosent come when i use i3 4gnb ram system

```
for (int i = 1; i <= frameno; i++)
{
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(1024,1280);
    Int32 s32MemID;
    Camera.Memory.GetActive(out s32MemID);
    Camera.Memory.CopyToBitmap(s32MemID, out bm);
    bm.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    String str = "";
    if (i < 10)
    {
        str = "00";
    }
    else if (i < 100)
    {
        str = "0";
    }
    bm.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\\capture" + str + i + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp); 
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
}
```

please some one give me the solution it is very imp for me

Comment: is it during the saving or at another time your GDI+ error comes? Do you really need to create a new bitmap in each loop, or could you do with reusing the bitmap by defining it before the loop? Do you dispose your image at the end of the loop? Ever heard of `i.ToString().PadLeft('0', 3)` to add the 00's to the indexer, why and how long is the delay in your loop. And which Camera library do you seem to be using?

Comment: Its a Private camera lib and delay is about 500 and error comes while saving bmp

Comment: You can start by puting your code inside a `using` block like this `using(Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(1024,1280)) { ... }`. Maybe this can solve your problem, even not it's the right way to handle `IDisposable` resources.

Comment: Is it possible to show at least how the out Bitmap variable is used / created / filled in the Camera.Memory.CopyToBitmap ?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria I agree with you and was writing an answer on the line of that aswell but in this case the out parameter is slightly bottering me?

Comment: @Icepickle right i didn't see it at first look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess with some refactoring it could be made more memory friendly, by using, eg:

```
Int32 s32MemID;
Bitmap bm;
string targetPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
for (int i = 1; i <= frameno; i++)
{
    try
    {
        Camera.Memory.GetActive(out s32MemID);
        Camera.Memory.CopyToBitmap(s32MemID, out bm);
        bm.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
        bm.Save(Path.Combine(targetPath, "capture" + (i.ToString().PadLeft('0', 3)) + ".bmp"), ImageFormat.Bmp); 
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (bm != null) 
        {
            bm.Dispose();
            bm = null;
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(delay);
}
```

Normally I would suggest the using pattern, but since you don't show how the `Camera.Memory.CopyToBitmap` method handles the out Bitmap parameter, it's hard to say how it should be done and if it's your own lib, I don't see why you would need the out parameter, since the bitmap would be passed by Reference anyhow)

Comment: Careful about the `out` - it could very well be that it's a poorly written P/Invoke, and that the proper modifier would be `ref` - `out` is not a feature of IL, just of C# (it gets translated to `ref` in IL). That said, it's already quite suspicious that an actual `Bitmap` object is passed... But yeah, definitely nicer and safer than OP's version.